# foreach is playing up

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have two arrays:

$item dates basicaly looks like this:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => 2012-05-28 
    [1] => 2012-05-29 
    [2] => 2012-05-30 
    [3] => 2012-05-31 
    [4] => 2012-06-01 
)
```

and  `$m['details']` looks like this:

```
Array (
    [details] => Array (
        [0] => Array (
            [Id] => 20003
            [MTimeInt] => 0
            [Date] => 2012-05-28
            [Name] => item
        )
        [1] => Array (
            [Id] => 20004
            [MTimeInt] => 1
            [Date] => 2012-05-29
            [Name] => item2
        )
        [2] => Array (
            [Id] => 20005
            [MealTimeInt] => 0
            [Date] => 2012-05-29
            [Name] => item3
        )
    )
)

//start of main bit
<?php foreach($m['details'] as $item) { ?>
<?php if($item['MTimeInt'] == 0 && $item['Date'] == $itemDates[0]) { ?> 
<?php echo $item['Name']; ?> <br>
<?php } ?>
<?php if($item['MTimeInt'] == 0 && $item['Date'] == $itemDates[1]) { ?> 
<?php echo $item['Name']; ?>
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

The problem I am having the foreach loop breaks after it has iterated once. When after the if statement has been fulfilled it should continue looping (by moving onto the next index/item onto the list) until all of the items have been checked.

I previously used a while loop without much success.

Any idea why this is happening?

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't you have a comma after each item you are declaring in your array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$m['details']` have only one element, look closer.

Maybe want you iterate over `$m['details']['details']` ?

Comment: Seems to work fine with one ['details'], as the "index" follows afterwards, made a mistake with how I did the foreach, corrected it, need to test it. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

If the code you show is correct, then inside $m['details'] there is another ['details'], which would explain the single iteration.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling foreach on a single array item. You should see what happens if you call it on $m singly and Seperate the items you need after with if. I will expand my answer properly when I get to a pc

Answer (score 0):

You are not iterating through the right array, in your case in the array you have only one item, try with $m['details']['details']